# Relacionamento entre três tabelas - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring, relacionamento

preciso fazer um relacionamento entre três tabelas no banco de dados em Java, criei as duas entidades e os métodos das duas entidades, agora preciso inserir uma tabela de relacionamento que possui apenas dois campos e cada um deles referenciando as respectivas entidades, alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Foto do Projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto do banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em termos de PostgreSQL você resolve com CREATE TABLE e a cláusula FOREIGN KEY. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Eu quero fazer em java

Comment: Fazer em java, você diz Hibernate?

Comment: Isso, fazer em hibernate!

Comment: @A.Carlos , você entende que quando você trabalha com Hibernate, você não precisa criar as tabelas dentro do banco? essa imagem é do seu banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, essa foto é do meu banco de dados

Comment: @A.Carlos pode inserir suas classes model?

Comment: Posso sim, só não sei como

Comment: @A.Carlos Coloca como codigo fonte as duas classes